# How to sort 2 dimensional array (matrix) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I want to sort a 2 dimensional array of integers. What is the simplest and most **readable** way to achieve this?

input:

```
[
    [3,4,2],
    [5,1,3],
    [2,6,1],
]
```

output:

```
[
    [1,1,2],
    [2,3,3],
    [4,5,6]
]
```

Comment: [Flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) it, [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it, chunk it.

Comment: Interesting problem, but what would the purpose be?  Where would sorting a matrix be solution relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd need the deeper arrays to be in order as well, I'd tackel it like so:

1. Flatten the arrays using [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), so get just a regular list

   ```js
   input.flat()
   ```
2. Sort them using a custom [integer sort function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly)

   ```js
   .sort((a, b) => a - b)
   ```
3. Re-create the second dimension

   ```js
   array_chunks(sortedArray, 3);
   ```

   <sub>(Function used taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8495740/5625547))</sub>

---

```js
const input = [
    [3,4,2],
    [5,1,3],
    [2,6,1],
];
const array_chunks = (array, chunk_size) => Array(Math.ceil(array.length / chunk_size)).fill().map((_, index) => index * chunk_size).map(begin => array.slice(begin, begin + chunk_size));

let result = array_chunks(input.flat().sort((a, b) => a - b), 3);
console.log(result);
```

```json
[
  [ 1, 1, 2 ], 
  [ 2, 3, 3 ], 
  [ 4, 5, 6 ]
]
```

Comment: You need a numeric sort. It's working here only because all are single digits

Answer (score 1):

When working with nested arrays, its common to work from the inner most level and then step out. Using this method, we start with the inner arrays:

```
// Sorting the inner most array
var result = [];
[
  [3,4,2],
  [5,1,3],
  [2,6,1],
].forEach(function(row) {  // a for loop could work as well, this is just shorter.
  result.push(row.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a-b; // ascending 
    // return b-a; // descending 
  }));
});
```

Then, you sort the outer array. You cannot sort the outer array as a single number, so its necessary to decide on a method. Examples being: average of the array, lowest value, or highest value.

```
// Using the first value to sort the outer array.
[
  [2,3,4],
  [1,3,5],
  [1,2,6],
].sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[0]-b[0];
});
```

Alternatively

The wanted output "[[1,1,2],[2,3,3],[4,5,6]]" disregards the inner arrays so it doesn't seem practical. To do this however, we'd reconstruct all inner arrays into one, sort, and then rebuild a nested array assuming each new array is to have 3 values.

```
  var oneDimensionalArray = [];
  var finalArray = [];
  [
    [3,4,2],
    [5,1,3],
    [2,6,1],
  ].forEach(function(row) {
    oneDimensionalArray = oneDimensionalArray.concat(row);
  });
  oneDimensionalArray.sort();
  for (var i=0; i<oneDimensionalArray.length; i++) {
    if (i%3==0) {
      temp = [];
    } 
    temp.push(oneDimensionalArray[i]);
    if (i%3==2) {  // 3 per line (0-2)
      finalArray.push(temp);
    }
  }
```

Again, I don't see this having practical usefulness. It would be easier to leave them as a regular array or start with a different setup if all the data is to be used in a way that disregards grouping/array.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general approach of nested array, which could have more nested arrays or different lengths.

It works by taking an array of indices to every value, a flat array of values and finally by assigning all values back to their place.

```js
const
    getIndices = (value, index) => Array.isArray(value)
        ? value.flatMap(getIndices).map(array => [index, ...array])
        : [[index]],
    setValue = (array, keys, value) => {
        const last = keys.pop();
        keys.reduce((a, i) => a[i] ??= [], array)[last] = value;
        return array;
    }; 
    data = [[3, 4, 2], [5, 1, 3], [2, 6, 1]],
    references = data.flatMap(getIndices),
    result = data
        .flat()
        .sort((a, b) => a - b)
        .reduce((r, v, i) => setValue(r, references[i], v), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```